# Minimal Cycle of Cycles

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of cycles of varying length, how do I calculate the minimal cycle that encompasses them all?  An example would be finding when all the planar bodies of a set of orbital periods align or a set of non-planar bodies repeat a given state.

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: I may have my answer.  I tried an algorithmic approach that brute forced adding cycles across the set until I got an alignment of all the cycles.  It turned out this was the same answer as I get from calculating the least common multiple (lcm).  So I believe lcm is the tool I am looking for.  Of course, I have to apply it to a set of values and not just two.  So lcm(a,b) = a*b/gcd(a,b), and for a set of numbers it becomes lcm(n1, n2, n3, ...) = lcm( n1, lcm(n2, lcm(n3, ...))) which I can do non-recursively.